# Advise finding the problem with the search crawler

Tags: search, search-results

I have just setup an instance of Sharepoint 2013 foundation and created a new site with a couple files on it, the problem is that that the search service always reports "Searchable Items: 0", I'm new to sharepoint and tried to look at the log file but it is simply huge, there are new log file entries almost every second and I can't seem to find a usable error message.
I appreciate any help that could help me find the problem with the search crawler.
Thanks,
Paulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with permissions, does the default crawl account have access to the content. Next look at crawl logs. I don't spend any time in Foundation, but in Server you can review the crawl logs for the content source and get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have the search app under a user called "sp_services", a domain user that is db_owner of the WS_CONTENT database and also an owner on the SharePoint website, when I look at the logs I don't see errors, just a lot of messages, I'm posting some here, maybe you idenfity something.

Comment: CSSFeedersManager statistics Regular Crawl group: #items in plugin 0; #items in batches ready to submit: 0; # submitted = 0

Comment: CSSFeedersManager statistics Regular Crawl group: there are no active feeders or none of the feeders ever submitted any items

Comment: CSSFeedersManager statistics Continuous Crawl group: #items in plugin 0; #items in batches ready to submit: 0; # submitted = 0

Comment: @paul-2011 does the crawl account have a full read policy on the Web Application (it should by default)? Looking at the errors it seems that the SSA may not be fully (or correctly) provisioned. I don't work in Foundation, so I raelly can't help much more.

Comment: yes that's correct, sp_services has read permissions on the website for the Search Craw Account (I checked under User Policy for the website). Do you think it's safe to follow the guides on the internet to recreate the search service on 2013?

Comment: Sure, provided you follow someone reputable like Gary Lapointe: http://blog.aptillon.com/2013/02/28/provisioning-search-on-sharepoint-2013-foundation-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I actually just fixed it by going to "Central Administration" -> "Search Service Application" -> "Manage Content Sources" and by starting the crawl process manually, after it finished I set up a chronogram to run a partial crawl every 60 minutes.